# (Mercurial) Is it ok to commit and push a line of code to different branch that already exists in another?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch

I'm in a rare situation where I'm not allowed to merge two branches but one line of code would be needed in both branches.

Will it cause problems if I commit and push this identical, same line of code to both of these branches. They won't cause a conflict in later merge since the lines are identical, right?

I know this is far from good practice but is it possible to do this without causing problems?

Answer (score 0):

That should be feasible without any problems and I haven't encountered any so far for the same situation - especially as mercurial provides a native command to copy a commit from one head to another:

if this one line change is present in the other branch in a separate commit, you can use the built-in mercurial command `graft` to copy the commit on top of your currently checked-out changeset: `hg graft -rXXX`